# How do I declare a range within an array using an enumeration in Ada?

Tags: types, ada, enumeration

Say we have a type representing a box of a dozen donuts,

```
type Bakers_Dozen is range 1 to 13;  -- Indices from 1 to 6 are donuts
```

Each **Donut** has a unique value that's within **Bakers_Dozen**:

```
subtype Donut is Bakers_Dozen (Plain, Chocolate, Strawberry, Glazed, Blueberry, Cannabis);
for Donut use (Plain=>1, Chocolate=>2, Strawberry=>3, Glazed=>4, Blueberry=>5, Cannabis=>6);
```

The intent is to refer to a Donut by either its name or value and ensure it only occupies range 1..6 of an array.

Unfortunately, my code results in an error message "incorrect constraint for this kind of type."

```
  PastriesBox[Plain].Message = "Plain Donut is boring but costs less";
  PastriesBox[Donut'Last].Message = "Please read contradictions and disclaimer inside box.";
  PastriesBox[12].Message = "A great tasting muffin with fresh goat milk.";
```

Is there a way of declaring a range of an array as an enumeration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some different means you can go about doing this.  The simplest is to declare a constant array using Donuts as the index and Bakers_Dozen as the Element type for the array.  Then you just use the array to convert the indexes:

```ada
package Indexes is
    type Bakers_Dozen is range 1 .. 13;  -- Indices from 1 to 6 are donuts
    type Donut is  
        (Plain, 
         Chocolate, 
         Strawberry, 
         Glazed, 
         Blueberry, 
         Cannabis);
    
    To_Index : constant array (Donut'Range) of Bakers_Dozen :=
        (Plain      => 1,
         Chocolate  => 2,
         Strawberry => 3,
         Glazed     => 4,
         Blueberry  => 5,
         Cannabis   => 6);
    
    
end Indexes;
```

Then you can do:

```ada
P1 : array(Indexes.Bakers_Dozen'Range) of Integer;
```

and

```ada
P1(Indexes.To_Index(Indexes.Plain)) := 2;
```

An alternative to this method is to ensure that Donuts is the same size as Bakers_Dozen and then use Ada.Unchecked_Conversion to convert a Donut object to a Bakers_Dozen object

```ada
package Conversions is
    type Bakers_Dozen is range 1 .. 13;  -- Indices from 1 to 6 are donuts
    type Donut is 
        (Plain, 
         Chocolate, 
         Strawberry, 
         Glazed, 
         Blueberry, 
         Cannabis)
    with Size => Bakers_Dozen'Size;
    
    for Donut use
        (Plain      => 1,
         Chocolate  => 2,
         Strawberry => 3,
         Glazed     => 4,
         Blueberry  => 5,
         Cannabis   => 6);
         
    function To_Index is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(Donut,Bakers_Dozen);
    
end Conversions;
```

Then you can do:

```ada
P2 : array(Conversions.Bakers_Dozen'Range) of Integer;
```

and

```ada
P2(Conversions.To_Index(Conversions.Chocolate)) := 3;
```

If you want to get fancy you can also wrap one of those methods into a private type and use more advanced concepts such as ["Reference_Type"](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-4-1-5.html#I2457) objects and the aspects [Variable_Indexing and Constant_Indexing](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-4-1-6.html#I2469) to make your private type act like an array

```ada
package Wrappers is

    type Bakers_Dozen is range 1 .. 13;  -- Indices from 1 to 6 are donuts
    type Donut is 
        (Plain, 
         Chocolate, 
         Strawberry, 
         Glazed, 
         Blueberry, 
         Cannabis);
         
    type Bakers_Array is tagged private
    with
        Variable_Indexing => Element;
        
    type Element_Holder(Element : access Integer) is null record
        with Implicit_Dereference => Element;
        
    function Element
        (Self  : aliased in out Bakers_Array;
         Index : Donut)
         return Element_Holder;
    function Element
        (Self  : aliased in out Bakers_Array;
         Index : Bakers_Dozen)
         return Element_Holder;
         
    

private

    type Element_Array is array (Bakers_Dozen'Range) of aliased Integer;

    type Bakers_Array is tagged record
        Elements : Element_Array;
    end record;
    
    To_Index : constant array (Donut'Range) of Bakers_Dozen :=
        (Plain      => 1,
         Chocolate  => 2,
         Strawberry => 3,
         Glazed     => 4,
         Blueberry  => 5,
         Cannabis   => 6);
    
    function Element
        (Self  : aliased in out Bakers_Array;
         Index : Donut)
         return Element_Holder
    is (Element => Self.Elements(To_Index(Index))'Access);
    
    function Element
        (Self  : aliased in out Bakers_Array;
         Index : Bakers_Dozen)
         return Element_Holder
    is (Element => Self.Elements(Index)'Access);

end Wrappers;
```

Then you can do:

```ada
P3 : Wrappers.Bakers_Array;
```

and

```ada
P3(Wrappers.Strawberry) := 4;
```

NOTE:  I didn't add the Constant_Indexing aspect to save on typing, but you might want that too.  You can look at Ada.Containers.Vectors to see how this is done.

There are probably other methods, but these are just off the top of my head.

Note also that I am just using Integers as the array elements for simplicity.  You can always make these arrays of other types.

Answer (score 1):

If your base type is an integer type, the subtype is an integer type. You can't make it an enumeration type.

You can declare constants for your Donuts if you want, then you can refer to them by name. You can instead give the other values names and then have `Bakers_Dozen` be an enumeration type. If arithmetic operations do semantically not make sense on values of your type, it shouldn't be an integer type anyway.

Comment: Correct. Arithmetic values don't semantically make sense on the values of my type and it's why I am trying to avoid it. I did think about giving the other values names. It would be doable in this example, but for a large or undefined size array, it's not practical.

Comment: @ATL_DEV It seems to be a specification problem. Either the array size is not statically known, then the index is to be an integer, or it *is* known, then every value is known and can be named. If a part of the array is statically known and the other isn't, you can make two arrays with separate index types, then one can be your enumeration. But this all is very much of a complex design decision and there's probably not the one correct answer for it.

Comment: Well, it so happens my array(1...12) is statically known, but only the lower half 1..6 is known and named.  The rest is also known, but it's a matter of what do you name them? p6,p7,p8?  It would be nice to refer to the lower half using enums and the rest using an index.

Comment: @ATL_DEV The question is, *why* do you have names for the first six items, but not for the other six? Are the first six constant and can never change, but the last six are slots where you can fill with different items? Such a setup implies a semantic difference between the two partitions of your array, and if such a difference indeed exists, then it would be better to have two arrays of length 6 as I suggested before. If there is no semantic difference, why don't you, for example, name 12 `Goat_Milk_Muffin`, matching the description you give in the example code.

Comment: My question is really a paraphrase. I was worried it might get in the way of understanding my question. I am modeling Apple's ADB system. All devices on the bus have an address from 0x0 to 0xF.  The first 8 addresses are default addresses designated to devices based on their type (enums). If two or more devices are the same type, the first one to respond get the default address and the rest gets placed in the other upper half. I'm afraid I will lose the ability to treat it like memory as a contagious whole that can be interated over.

Comment: An array of enumerations must be an array of a single type. Different enumeration values are not separate types. They are separate values of the same type. If you want to refer to an enumeration value by a number use the 'Pos attribute to arrive at a corresponding number. Remember that Ada allows arrays to be indexed by any discrete type, including enumerated types.

Comment: @ATL_DEV It sounds like you'll want to have a getter function that takes the enum and returns either the index or directly a value from the array, and then have the array indexed with an integer. That seems to be the best mapping for the use-case „give me the registered device for the default address named *X*“.

Comment: I presume you need to store more about the device at an address than just its kind; otherwise your problem is trivial. What it sounds like you want is a map Address => Device_Info, where Device_Info includes the device kind, and the kind is fixed for the first 8 devices. For that I would think an array with a Dynamic_Predicate would do what you want: `type Device_Map is array (Device_Address) of Device_Info with Dynamic_Predicate => (for all A in Fixed_Address => Device_Map (A).Kind = Fixed_Kind (A) );`

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter  Sound like what I am looking for. I need to learn more dynamic predicates and how to use them. Specifically,how to access a device at the default address or another address. On a side note, I am pleasantly surprised Ada has such "modern" constructs expressed  in such an elegant way! All this time the conventional wisdom is that Ada is an crufty 80s language on life support ready to die at a moments notice.

Comment: If Ada is a crufty 80s language, then so is C++, while I suppose C is a crufty 70s language. Ada has been revised in 1995, 2007, and 2012, with another revision being prepared and hopefully appearing this year. Ada remains the language of choice for S/W that has to be correct, so it's unlikely to die any time soon.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter Agreed. I really like the expressiveness of Ada and its unfortunately badly undersold as a language. It's in fact more than a safe language. It's touches several paradigms found in other languages. After specifying your data structures, the actually implementation is small with everything easily falling into place. It is eerily similar to LISPs decomposition style of programming. Ada's main deficiency is it's interfacing with platform APIs.